# how to find circle of curvature centre point

Tags: calculus, vectors, circles, curvature

For this question I am asked to find the *radius and centre-point* of the
circle of curvature for the following function:

> $−7.87e^{2.65x}$

I calculate the radius correctly with the formula:  $R =\frac{1}{ρ}$
which is:

R = 0.9838228573
[working out for radius](https://i.stack.imgur.com/647Mo.png)

However, when it comes to finding *the centre-point* I have been getting it wrong every time.

I use this formula I found online to do so:

> $x+R\times\frac{dy}{dx}, y+R$

does anyone know another method I could use to find the centrepoint ?

I have seen vector variations which come to the right answer but I dont understand them very much :/
Thank you all ! for any help it is appreciated